Affadavit query
I got a name change affadavit for my wife done this year since her name was changed in the passport after we got married 10 yrs earlier. I did this since the marriage certificate had her maiden name obviously. Will this be an issue when applying for a uk or schengen visa? I mean the last name in the passport and marriage certificate are different

This question should have gone on the site. It does not belong on the meta site.
